# Equivalence of input-restricted and output-restricted deques

Tags: algorithms, queues

There is a question in Art of Computer Programming by Knuth which needs us to prove that input-restricted deques and output-restricted deques can form the same number of (and possibly individually same) permutations. The solution is

> By operating backwards, we can get the reverse of the inverse of the reverse of
>   any input-restricted permutation with an output-restricted deque, and conversely. This
>   rule sets up a one-to-one correspondence between the two sets of permutations.

Which doesn't seem very clear. Can someone explain the answer in English?

Comment: answered https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3666972/514376